# Set up GitHUB for Multiple Sources: Getting started

Tags: git, github

I just started with GitHub and need to setup a complex project:

The code is highly encapsulated in the sense that independent executables complete different functions. I have source files in C++, Perl, VB.NET, Javascript, Java, and ActionScript3.

I work on Windows using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop, FlashDevelop, Vim, and Strawberry Perl. I have TortoiseGit installed. The projects are located in different local folders and on multiple computers, and I have a GitHub account with a private repository.

How do I synchronize different folders from different sources with GitHub?

Comment: After additional research: Should I be using different namespaces?

Comment: I guess one solution is to use submodules, but that would require multiple Git projects: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/161293/choosing-between-single-or-multiple-projects-in-a-git-repository